# A synonym for a co-worker

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the best way to describe soldiers with which you did not serve directly in this sentence:

> “who plans a similar attack to avenge his colleagues, annihilated in the false war that followed...”

I found compatriots or comrades. Any other one-word ideas?

Comment: *brothers in arms*

Answer (score 2):

**Comrades in arms** comes to mind, or as suggested earlier, brothers in arms.

Just re read your question and realized you were looking for one word. In that case I'd go with **comrades** or **compatriots**. If they were sailors, **shipmates**.

Answer (score 1):

**Peers?** You could add the nationality to add context eg "his German peers".

*"A person who is the same age or has the same social position or the same abilities as other people in a group"* (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: They are US soldiers - You have answered my other question (9/11 psychiatrist) from which came this one. Comrades gets a bigger hit on Google Ngram. Is there any other word that would be a better pick as a synonym for US ground troops then comrades or compatriots?

Comment: I think in that sense comrades or compatriots are the best, most synonyms will fall short somehow. It might be best to source out a veteran somewhere and ask them how they refer to their fellow soldiers.